# register schema from Json while using kafka AvroConverter

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to mirror topic from a source Kafka cluster into destination Kafka cluster using this open library [COMCAST](https://github.com/Comcast/MirrorTool-for-Kafka-Connect). My source topic has json payload along with schema and i am trying to mirror this topic to destination kafka. Also i am converting it to avro while writing to destination topic. Hence i am using Kafka Avro Converter [avro converter](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/connect.html).

source kafka topic contains following payload along with schema

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "id"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "name"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "email"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "department"
      },
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": false,
        "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "updated_at"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false,
    "name": "test"
  },
  "payload": {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "harry",
    "email": "harry@gmail.com",
    "department": "sales",
    "updated_at": 1584976391000
  }
}
```

below is my kafka connector curl to

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "name": "kafka-connect-kafka-source-example-source-3",
  "config": {
    "tasks.max": "2",
    "connector.class": "com.comcast.kafka.connect.kafka.KafkaSourceConnector", 
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "source.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "source.topic.whitelist": "topic_test",
    "topic.preserve.partitions": "true",
    "source.auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
    "source.group.id": "kafka-connect-testing-3",
    "connector.consumer.reconnect.backoff.max.ms": "10000",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081/",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081/",
  }
}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

**problem-**
It mirrors the topic but doesn't convert the payload to avro format. And registered schema looks like following.

```
{"subject":"topic_test-value","version":1,"id":1,"schema":"[\"null\",\"bytes\"]"}
```

Comment: Why use MirrorTool? https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/mirror

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for the connector I think you should probably be setting `source.value.deserializer` to `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`, and assuming that it follows standard Kafka Connect practice set `source.value.deserializer.schemas.enable` to `true`.

You might want to look at MirrorMaker 2, which is now part of Apache Kafka and provides similar Kafka Connect-based replication functionality.

Comment: then what about avro and schema. how i'll achieve ?

Comment: @AashishVerma Your data is not Avro. Why did you think it was?

Comment: `schemas.enable` defaults to true, by the way